# How to clear form on postback?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there a simple way to clear the value of server controls on postback? I have tried ViewState.clear() and it doesn't do anything. The page I am working on inherits from a Masterpage that has viewstate enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either have to redirect back to the same page or clear the controls manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect back to the page.

```
Response.Redirect(pathToPage);
```

This *is* however an extra round-trip (response to the browser that will re-request the page).

Another option is to recurse through the controls hierarchy, clearing each control in turn.

Answer (score 0):

You tried `ClearChildViewState()`?

Comment: I was hoping for a simple method like this, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can clear all controls in your form using this:

```
form1.Controls.Clear()
```